# Proofs with Fibonacci and Lucas numbers via induction

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

How would I go about proving the following sequence using induction on $k$?

$2F_{2n+k} = F_{n+k}L_n + F_nL_{n+k}$

I know I have to show that it's true for $k = 1$, but I can't even seem to be able to do that.

Comment: What about $k=0$ ? Also, express everything in terms of the Fibonacci numbers alone.

Comment: @YvesDaoust k = 0 would be nice to try, but when doing induction, I have been taught to first use k = 1 prior to doing the inductive step. Also, I tried rewriting everything in terms of just fibonacci numbers, but the k has been throwing me off.

Comment: No, you can establish a base case for any $k$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, I wasn't aware of that! Thank you.

Comment: So when doing the induction on k, if I was to do it for k + 1, how would I go about rewriting the equation such that everything is only in terms of fibonacci and not the lucas numbers?

Comment: Hem, what's relation between both ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well I know these relations: Ln = Fn-1 + Fn+1, and I have been told that F2n = FnLn. In this case, would I just use these, but add the k in there, or would that be incorrect?

Comment: $n$ can be anything.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If n can be anything, does that mean I can substitute k+1 in for n, even though the problem asked to do induction on k? Or does that mean I can use any value for n, like say n = 1, and still do the induction? (I'm so sorry for all the questions, but my textbook doesn't have any examples of a problem like this for me to try to understand.)

Comment: I can substitute k+1 in for n

Comment: Oh, alright. That makes a lot more sense. I wasn't sure if that was something that could be done, that I would need to replace k with k+1 to do the induction on k. Thank you so much for the help. Greatly appreciate it. So when plugging k+1 in for n, I still have the lucas numbers remaining there. In order to rewrite them in terms of fibonacci, would I just use the relations I mentioned before to do so, or is there another step I would need to do?